# Asynctask does not complete

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have a asynctask  that I use to do some calculations and then write those values to a file. Every so often I will call this Asynctask. Sometimes the doInBackground () function does not finish. Not sure if it gets stuck in a loop or something. Any further calls to the Asynctask  will not work. The onpostexecute() function does not get called either. Why is this happening?

I call the Asyntask like this:

```
     MyAsyntask task = new MyAsyntask();
                        task.execute();




 @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

         short sample=0;
            try {

                int sampleCount = 200;

                short[] data = new short[sampleCount];

                int o = 0;
                int index = 0;
                while (sampleCount > 0) {

                    sample= (sample+1)/(2)//


                    data[o] = sample ;
                   o++;
                    --sampleCount;

                }

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TestAPP");
                File file = new File(f, "Test" + ".txt");
                try {
                    DataOutputStream out = null;

                    out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));

                    for(int i=0; i< data.length; i++)
                    {

                        if(data[i]>=0)
                        {
                            out.writeShort(1);

                        }else
                        {
                            out.writeShort(0);
                        }




                    }
                    out.close();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it to know where it gets stuck?

Comment: @cuoka- I was not able to recreate the problem when I was debugging.

Comment: What do you mean? Does it happen randomly? You could try to print some logs. BTW: you have a missing double quote in TextAPP.

Comment: @cuoka- yes, It will happen randomly. I can Have it working for hours with out a problem. Then the DoinBackground() will not run.

Comment: Hard to help you without a stacktrace

Comment: `int o = 0;`. Insane using one character variable names. Especially when you call them `o`.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code to be honest, I would print some logs and retry until it fails again.

Comment: An infinite loop doesn't look like an option. The file operations might be the heaviest operations done there. As `AsyncTask`s are run in a queue by default in modern Android versions, the operations might take a while and if the `AsyncTask` is called very frequently, then maybe at some point the calls start piling up: The older one is not finished when a new one is already queued. But what would the end result be? (Not a rhetorical question.) Could that piling up consume the stack or heap and could it overflow? I can't say that just off the top of my head. Maybe somebody can. Anyone? :)